# How to leave out some System.out/logging statements while executing java code?

Tags: java

In C++ if we do not want some statements to compile into code that ships like assert function calls, we control their compilation through #ifndef preprocessor directives.

How do we do this in Java?

I have some System.out.println() statements for debugging which I would like to remove for the final code.

one way is to make them execute conditionally under the affect of a boolean variable. Is there a better way of doing this?

As I have a java swing application I can turn off the System.out.println statements without affecting the output. What is the method of doing this?

Comment: You should have used a logger like Log4j for printing debugging information. It would then be easy to turn them off or change the logging level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a logging framework like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.com). You can print to the console in debugging and omit everything in production without recompiling the application.

Comment: Actually, recompilation is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you; it was a typo. I wrote "with recompiling", which doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Use logging. See log4j or commons logging.

Generally, each log entry has a severity level (like debug, info, warning, error) and you can configure which are printed from the application. You can print all of them for debug, but only some (e.g. info and higher) in production. The configuration is usually done with a single plain text file.

Logging frameworks can do more than that: Add more detail automatically (e.g. timestamp or thread ID), log to console, file and/or database, rotate files, and more.

Answer (score 3):

Use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for those pieces of code which you want added or removed at compile time and compile without AspectJ when you don't want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

In general (not only for your example), you can create multiple implementations of an interface, and change, which instance is used during execution. This is called [**polymorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), the advantage over if/else is: you choose the implementation **once**, instead of every time it's used.

In Java, polymorphism does not result in performance overhead.

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void trashTheCPU();
}

public class MyRealImpl implements MyInterface {
  @Override
  public void trashTheCPU() {
    // actually trash the CPU with heavy tasks
  }
}

public class MyEmptyImpl implements MyInterface {
  @Override
  public void trashTheCPU() {
    // do nothing
  }
}

// ... somewhere else:

MyInterface mi = null;

public void initEveryting() {
  if(trashTheCPUconditionIsMet) {
    mi = new MyRealImpl();
  } else {
    mi = new MyEmptyImpl();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you're doing, assertions may be the way to go.  The `assert` keyword was added to Java in version 1.4, and is conceptually similar to C++'s `assert()`, which I see you're familiar with.

`assert` statements in Java do nothing if they evaluate to true and yell at you otherwise, which is perfect for debugging.  They also don't work by default, which means that the compiler will ignore them unless you explicitly tell it not to.  The end result is a debugging tool that "evaporates" when you ship your production code.

Here's [Sun's tutorial on Java `assert`s](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html).

Comment: Java asserts are useless precisely because they are disabled by default - they should have to be intentionally disabled in production environments, not the other way around.  Furthermore, they may execute side-effect statements in the hands of people who don't really understand them - such that if they are turned on or off, the code no longer functions properly.  A logging framework is a much better solution.